# Prestashop 1.3.6 to 1.4.1

Tags: prestashop

I have an eshop running PS 1.3.6 version. On my local I've updated to 1.4 first and then to 1.4.1...

Now I would like to update on server... is it possible to just upload files from my local 1.4.1, adjust the settings file and run the update script from 1.4.1 directly (without the middle step to 1.4)?

I can see there are database update scripts for each version, so it should be safe to do it like that, but I want to be sure before I run it on server.... thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am usually doing the major upgrades this way:

1. Take a snapshot of the current site (tar.gz) & backup database using mysqldump tool (for compatibility);
2. Download all the files and setup the site on your local server machine using database dump (via mysql command) and downloaded snapshot. Adjust settings if necessary.
3. Perform an upgrade on your local site, thoroughly test it and test it again with your code & theme.
4. Repackage your updated files and database (tar.gz & mysqldump) and upload them to the server.
5. Erase the old site and untar upgraded site to its folder to take its place.
6. Replace old database with an upgraded one (using mysql command on the server).
7. Adjust settings if necessary. Test and run it! :)

That should be all. If you're more advanced you could optimize most of the steps. Give me a shout if you need all the useful commands to back up and restore files & DB.